How to merge efficientNet.pth into yolo11.pt?
I've changed the YOLO's backbone to efficientNet. Since I don't want to training from scratch that I'm looking for a way to combine the efficientNet pretrained parameter and the yolo.pt file.
But when I use torch.load() to load the pretrained model and print them. I found they are very different.
In yolo.pt it contains many informations about the models such as epochs, data.yaml, model structure and so on, while there are only state_dict() in efficientNet.pth. How should I combine them?
How should I combine them?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
